# Unique constraint is not honoured when specified with IS_IN_DB in web2py

Tags: data-access-layer, web2py

I defined a table as follows:

```
db.define_table('special_users',
    Field('sp_user', db.auth_user, required=True, notnull=True, label='Special User', represent=lambda lead,row: lead.first_name + ' ' + lead.last_name, unique=True),
    format=lambda row: (row.lead.first_name + ' ' + row.lead.last_name) or 'N/A')
```

And I specified the requires constraint as follows

```
db.special_users.lead.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.auth_user, '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s', zero=None)
```

Now, when I generate a form for the table using `SQLFORM(db.special_users)` it allows me to add a user as many times as I want, which is a violation of `unique=True` constraint. How can I get this rectified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I think maybe notnull and unique constraints don't get applied to reference fields. In any case, if inserts are generally made via forms, you are better off using an [`IS_NOT_IN_DB()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#Database-validators) validator on the field, as that will enable proper error handling and display when processing the form. Relying only on `unique=True` would result in an exception upon a duplicate insert attempt, which would generate a non-specific 500 server error for the end user.

Comment: Doing so removes the dropdown and the user has to give the id as input in a text field. Finally, had to generate my own form instead of relying on SQLFORM to generate one.

Comment: If you read the documentation for the [`IS_IN_DB()` validator](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#Database-validators), it shows you how to retain the dropdown while still using additional validators (in fact, the example shown includes the `IS_NOT_IN_DB()` validator). You do not need to generate your own form.